# SwiftUI - Presentation variables not updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have multiple sheets and have had to create a function to handle some of the work, as multiple `.sheet` declarations are essentially impossible.

On tap of a `Button`, the variable containing the type of sheet is updated (`activatedViewShown`) and the variable which triggers the sheet is set to `true`. \

I've tried putting `fatalError` statements in the `Button action` to check and make sure the `activatedViewShown` variables were updated correctly but they're never triggered, showing they were correctly set. I additionally made the variable itself `optional` for more safety.

However, when calling the sheet and `sheetContent()` function, it rips right through the if statements (also tried switch) to the fatalError I placed. What's happening here?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    
    @FetchRequests ... medicationBlocks, medications
    
    // MARK: View presentation variables
    enum sheetViews {
        case block, medication, profile
    }
    @State var activatedViewShown: sheetViews?
    @State var isSheetShown: Bool = false

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(medicationBlocks) { block in
                    MedicationBlockView(medicationBlock: block)
                }
                .if(medicationBlocks.count < 1) {
                    $0.overlay(
                        Button(action: {
                                let haptic = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                                haptic.impactOccurred()
                                self.activatedViewShown = .block
                                self.isSheetShown = true
                        }, label: {
                            MedicationBlocksEmptyLabel()
                        }))
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Today")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        self.activatedViewShown = .profile
                        self.isSheetShown = true
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    })
                )
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetShown, content: sheetContent)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func sheetContent() -> some View {
        if self.activatedViewShown == .block {
            AddBlock().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        } else if self.activatedViewShown == .medication {
            AddMedication(medicationBlocks: medicationBlocks).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        } else if self.activatedViewShown == .profile {
            ProfileView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

***Disclaimer**: I am on Xcode 12, so this *could* be a bug, so I wanted to check first. Some code, such as the FetchRequests were shortened.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)